# segmentation error when importing opencv in python with Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I installed opencv 2.4.2 in python 2.7.1 and everything works. Now I updated python to 2.7.3 with correct osx installer from python.org and when try to import opencv it tells me that there isn't a module named cv (for cv2 is the same). So I upgraded opencv to 2.4.3, I haven't received error during installation, but when I try to import opencv I receive:

```
segmentation fault: 11
```

I tried to change `PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH` in cmake file to correct location (old location not exist) but I received same error!

**SOLUTION:**

I've founded solution! I rollback to python 2.7.1, to do this in my home directory "/Users/emanuel" i've modified .bash_profile with content of .bash_profile.pysave that was a backup file of my old bash. After installation I have this schema:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I have simply deleted all after export instruction:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:
```

Now all works fine!